# Can Altium PDN Analyser Calculate AC Impedance?

Tags: altium, impedance, power-delivery

It looks like the new PDN Analyser v2.0 tool in Altium v21 can only calculate "steady-state" DC PDN impedances, which in itself is not that useful:

> There is no such thing as a steady-state in the PDS. The assumption being made is that things are static. This assumption flies in the face of what is the purpose of a PDS and how it operates. By definition, circuits attached to the PDS are active and not in the ‘steady-state’.
> *Lee Ritchey*

So I wonder if doing an AC sweep is at all possible. I've gone through the [Altium PDNA 2.0 Introductory Series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jAsUdfuCk0) but nothing relevant is mentioned there.

As an example, I'd be interested in analysing the impedance of interplane capacitances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to this [Introduction To PDN Analyzer Webinar Recap May 10, 2018](https://resources.altium.com/p/introduction-to-pdn-analyzer-webinar-recap-may-10-2018) this is on the roadmap. As far as I can see it has not been added just yet.

Relevant quotes from the linked article (see Q&A at the end):

> Q: Are there any plans to implement AC analysis?
>
> A: Yes, we plan to continue improve which includes adding AC analysis.

> Q: Can PDNA provide inductance of the power path?
>
> A: No. Reactive attributes of the copper structures are not calculated because PDNA currently focuses on DC.